# SQL Syntax Error db_query

Tags: mysql, sql, adminer

I am trying to run he following query from Adminer 4.6.2 and it gives me the vague "syntax error" with no further details:

```
 db_query("DELETE FROM {field_collection_item} WHERE field_name NOT IN (SELECT field_name FROM {field_config} WHERE type = 'field_collection')");
```

I have also tried this:

```
DELETE FROM {field_collection_item} WHERE field_name NOT IN (SELECT field_name FROM {field_config} WHERE type = 'field_collection')
```

but it returns the same syntax error.

Comment: Do not use curly brackets, use square braces instead for table `DELETE FROM [field_collection_item] WHERE field_name NOT IN (SELECT field_name FROM [field_config] WHERE type = 'field_collection')`

Comment: That still gives syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use double quotes, use 2 single quotes `''`, Filter condition requires value to be enclosed in single quotes.
It is always a good practice to verify your code you can do that by using Print @sql

EX:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max)

SET @sql = 'DELETE FROM [field_collection_item] WHERE field_name
               NOT IN (SELECT field_name FROM [field_config] WHERE type = ''field_collection'')'

PRINT @sql
```

Prints:

```
    DELETE FROM [field_collection_item] WHERE field_name NOT IN 
   (SELECT field_name FROM [field_config] WHERE type = 'field_collection')
```